# How to receive object information from within an array in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have two models, a posts model and a category model where I have an array that stores posts by objectId

Category Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        color: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        posts: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Post',
            required: false,
        }],
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
```

Post model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        img: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        category: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Category",
        },
        desc: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
  
module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

So I created a get by id category controller

```
const Category = require('../../models/Category');

class FindCategory {
    async find(req, res) {
        const { id } = req.params;

        try {
            const category = await Category.findById(id);

            return res.status(200).json(category);
        } catch (err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    }
} 

module.exports = new FindCategory();
```

The problem is that when I make this request in my postman, it returns me for example

```
{
    "_id": "63ac925d872445065a588f61",
    "name": "Games",
    "color": "#ff914d",
    "posts": [
        "63ac9cbccec4d9f35c4f4d1f"
    ],
    "createdAt": "2022-12-28T19:00:45.847Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-12-28T19:49:47.119Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

But I would like to render the information of each post inside the "posts" array, something like that for example

```
{
    "_id": "63ac925d872445065a588f61",
    "name": "Games",
    "color": "#ff914d",
    "posts": [
        "name": "red dead",
        "img": "example.png", 
        "category": "games",
        "desc": "test,
    ],
    "createdAt": "2022-12-28T19:00:45.847Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-12-28T19:49:47.119Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `populate` function provided by mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#setting-populated-fields

```js
Category.
  findById(...).
  populate('posts')
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is [useful without it](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259): add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable. If you [edit] this answer to add more once it is deleted, please flag it for moderator attention so that it can be un-deleted.